# sqlite database location node-red

Tags: sqlite, node-red, pm2

I have a Node-RED flow. It uses a sqlite node. I am using node-red-node-sqlite. My OS is Windows 10.

My sql database is configured just with name "db" :

[image]

My question is, where is located the sqlite database file?

I already search in the following places, but didn't found:

- C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-red
- C:\Users\user\.node-red

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I am also using pm2 with pm2-windows-service to start Node-RED.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify a full path to the file in the Database field it will create the file in the current working directory for the process, which will be where you ran either `node-red` or `npm start`.

Comment: I am using pm2 with pm2-windows-startup to start Node-RED. In this case, do you have an idea where it could be? Question updated. Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry I haven't touched a windows machine in 20 years (This is why you should always use a fully qualified path)

Comment: But I'd look for something in `C:\Users\user\.pm2`

Comment: I was not lucky to find the database at that location :(

Comment: Have you tried using Windows explorer's search option?

Comment: Yes, found nothing. My database name was just "db". No result related with an sqlite file.

Comment: I was not using pm2-windows-startup but pm2-windows-service. Don't know if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use full path location with file name.
It should work i guess.

Comment: Yes it works, but this does not answer my question, because I still don't know where the file is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This isn't a valid answer, just a workaround for those who have the same problem.**

I could't find my database file. But inside Node-RED everything worked just great. So. this is what I have done as a workaround:

1. In Node-RED, make some select nodes to get all data from tables
2. Store the tables values somewhere (in a .txt file or something like that)
3. Create your database outside Node-RED, somewhere like c:\sqlite\db.db. **Check read/write permissions**
4. Create the tables and insert the values stored from old database
5. In Node-RED, inside "Database", put the complete path of the database. For example, c:\sqlite\db.db

In my case this was easy because I only had two database with less than 10 rows.

Hope this can help others.

Anyway, still waiting for a valid answer :)